# New toolbar on mail selection like Gmail

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

In Android Gmail App, when one or more email is selected, the toolbar changes to white background with back button, delete button, etc.

How I can implement the same in Android L? I know how to add a back button in a new activity `(getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true))`, but unable to find this one.

Comment: do you mean [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu)

Comment: Exactly. thanks. Pls enter this as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find the guideline [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu)

For ListView or GridView, you may search `Enabling batch contextual actions in a ListView or GridView` for example below.

```
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                                          long id, boolean checked) {
        // Here you can do something when items are selected/de-selected,
        // such as update the title in the CAB
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        // Respond to clicks on the actions in the CAB
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_delete:
                deleteSelectedItems();
                mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu for the CAB
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        // Here you can make any necessary updates to the activity when
        // the CAB is removed. By default, selected items are deselected/unchecked.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // Here you can perform updates to the CAB due to
        // an invalidate() request
        return false;
    }
});
```